# std::function as argument of std::function

Tags: c++11, std-function

for example, I can do something like:

```
void foo(int i)
{
    std::cout << "fo is called with: " << i << "\n";
}

int main()
{
    std::function<void(int)> fo = std::bind(&foo, std::placeholders::_1);
    fo(5);
}
```

and output

> fo is called with: 5

now I'm curious about if I can make a std::function that receive a std::function as argument,so I think of some function like:

```
void foAndFo(function<void(int)> foo)
{
    std::function<void(int)> fo = std::bind(&foo, std::placeholders::_1);
    fo(5);
}
```

but this can even not been compiled.

now I changed to something may call function pointer.

```
using foType = void(*)(int);
void foAndFo(foType foo)
{
    std::function<void(int)> fo = std::bind(&foo, std::placeholders::_1);
    fo(5);
}
```

now it can be compiled.But now I cannot std::bind it like:

```
int main()
{
std::function<foType> fo2 = std::bind(&foAndFo,std::placeholders::_1); //error
}
```

is it possible to use std::function as argument of std::function?

Answer (score 2):

This is possible. Just drop the `&` before `foo` here:

```
void foAndFo(function<void(int)> fo)
{
    std::function<void(int)> fo = std::bind(/*&*/foo, std::placeholders::_1);
    fo(5);
}
```

The difference is that if `foo` is a `void(int)`, both `foo` and `&foo` can be inserted where a function is expected. On the other hand, if `foo` is a `std::function` then the two are quite different: `foo` can be passed for a `const std::function&`, but `&foo` is a `std::function*`, a pointer to an object of the type `std::function`. The latter is not Callable.

Minimal working example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

void foo(int i)
{
    std::cout << "fo is called with: " << i << "\n";
}

int main()
{
    std::function<void(int)> fo = std::bind(foo, std::placeholders::_1); // or &foo, both work
    std::function<void(int)> fo2 = std::bind(fo, std::placeholders::_1); // Error if &fo is used
    fo2(5);
}
```

Comment: thank you sir, but how do I bind std::function<foType> fo2 to foAndFo function?

Comment: @ggininder What would you like the result to do? Your `foAndFo` is a function that takes *another function* and returns `void`. You could not call it as a `void(int)`, so you can't bind it to a `std::function<void(int)>`. I can't see what that should mean.

Comment: in C# I can make a callback of a callback of a callback of a ..... if I cannot really modify the original code. I want to check if I can do similar in c++.

Comment: @ggininder Sorry, I'm really confused and your reply did not clarify it. Surely you can stack these things in various ways. Could you either edit an analogous C# code in your question, including a point where the `fo2` (bound to `foAndFo`) would be actually *called* or *used* in any way? I'll then edit my answer accordingly.